# How to convert year in Golang to Buddhist year

Tags: date, go, formatting

Basically, If I run this code I can get date

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("02/01/2006"))
```

My question is how to convert Go year to Buddhist year in this format?

**Note** a formula for converting year in A.D. to B.E format is

```
B.E. = A.D. + 543
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this way below has a bug in leap year.

```
t := time.Now()
buddhaTime = t.AddDate(543, 0, 0)
```

If the year is a leap year such as 2020, then the Buddhist year will be 2020+543 which is 2563. But Golang time will understand that 2563 is in the Christ year But actually, 2563 in Christ year is not a leap year. So, there will be a conflict on 29 Feb and 1 Mar in every leap year. For example, If you try to convert 29/02/2020, you will get 01/03/2563 as a result in buddhist era.

So I think the solution is to detect the leap year first and then handle the format.

```
func IsLeapYear(date time.Time) bool {
   endOfYear := time.Date(date.Year(), time.December, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
   day := endOfYear.YearDay()
   return day == 366
}
```

```
func ConvertDateToBuddhistEra(date time.Time) string {
   if IsLeapYear(date) {
      y := date.Year()+543
      return fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%d", date.Format("02"), date.Format("01"), y)
   }
   return date.AddDate(543, 0, 0).Format("02/01/2006")
}
```

an update format to the lib would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Well I highly doubt that a format string exists which will product Buddhist time so just do the simple straight forward thing and add 543 years to your date... You should probably use a constant for the `beDifference`.

```
t := time.Now()
buddhaTime = t.AddDate(543, 0, 0)
```